# validate md-datepicker date format as MM/DD/YYYY using a regular expression

Tags: angularjs, regex, datepicker, angular-material2

I just tried to validate md-datepicker date format as **MM/DD/YYYY** using a regular expression and [md-error](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#error-messages) in following way

this is the [Regular Expression](http://regexr.com/346hf) to accept **MM/DD/YYYY** format

```
const DOB_REGEX = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;
```

this is the **input-errors-example.ts** file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

const DOB_REGEX = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;

@Component({
  selector: 'input-errors-example',
  templateUrl: 'input-errors-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['input-errors-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorsExample {


    dobFormControl = new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(DOB_REGEX)
    ]);

}
```

this is the html code snippet for the above

```
<form class="example-form">

  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="dobFormControl" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 47' maxlength="10">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
    <md-error *ngIf="dobFormControl.hasError('required') || dobFormControl.hasError('pattern')">
      Please enter a valid Date
    </md-error>
  </md-form-field>

</form>
```

[this is the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xligly8abRKEuEAuJApC?p=preview) that relate to this problem.

this is running as usual, but for the valid date inputs, this once showing error message.

Beside I tried with different regular expressions, but same thing happen, is there any problem in my approach or how to overcome this issue

Comment: Your regex seems a little strange. How do you know it's ok ? And, what is it failing on ?

Comment: Yeah, your regex is fubar. Start over from scratch, it's not even close.

Comment: Leap years from 1900 - 2999 `19(?:0[48]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|2(?:[048](?:0[048]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|[1235679](?:0[48]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26]))`

Answer (score 2):

That regex looks messy.  I think this is something that will do what you want:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/
```

Give that a shot and you should be good to go.  This is pretty clean to read I think.  It's pretty much a hard coded range of 2 numbers, a delimiter (which you can change out), 2 more hard coded numbers, a delimiter, and 4 numbers (1900-2999).  This can be tweaked as perhaps you don't want 1900 for example.

--UPDATE, response to comment:
There must be something odd with how the javascript is being setup.  Here is a working python example:

```
import re

def main():
    theregex = re.compile("^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$")
    if re.search(theregex, "04/26/2017"):
        print ("match")

main()
```

Comment: I tried with your approach [like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/HrSP7wJN9xf3D1biApEJ?p=preview) but this one also not accepting valid dates

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try.
Tested and works with Leap Years.

(*could actually be pared down more.. oh well*)

MMDDYYYY for years 1900 - 2999

`^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])([/.-])(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\1|0?2([/.-])(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\2|(?:0?[469]|11)([/.-])(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\3|(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])([/.-])(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\4|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([/.-])0?2\5|(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)([/.-])(?:0?[469]|11)\6)(?:(?:19)?\d{2}|2\d{3})|(?:0?2([/.-])29\7|29([/.-])0?2\8)(?:19(?:0[48]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|2(?:[048](?:0[048]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26])|[1235679](?:0[48]|1[26]|2[048]|3[26]|4[048]|5[26]|6[048]|7[26]|8[048]|9[26]))))$`

Regexr demo  http://regexr.com/3go0m

```
 ^     
 (?:
      # Non-Leap Years
      (?:
           # Month Day 

           (?: 0? [13578] | 1 [02] )
           ( [/.-] )                     # (1)
           (?: 0? [1-9] | [12] \d | 3 [01] )
           \1 
        |  
           0?2
           ( [/.-] )                     # (2)
           (?: 0? [1-9] | 1 \d | 2 [0-8] )
           \2 
        |  
           (?: 0? [469] | 11 )
           ( [/.-] )                     # (3)
           (?: 0? [1-9] | [12] \d | 30 )
           \3              

        |                              # or
           # Day Month   

           (?: 0? [1-9] | [1-2] \d | 3 [0-1] )
           ( [/.-] )                     # (4)
           (?: 0? [13578] | 1 [02] )
           \4 
        |  
           (?: 0? [1-9] | 1 \d | 2 [0-8] )
           ( [/.-] )                     # (5)
           0?2
           \5 

        |  
           (?: 0? [1-9] | [12] \d | 30 )
           ( [/.-] )                     # (6)
           (?: 0? [469] | 11 )
           \6              

      )
      (?:                           # Year  1900 - 2999
           (?: 19 )?                     # 2 digits defaults to current century
           \d{2} 
        |  
           2 \d{3} 
      )
   |  
      # Leap Years
      (?:
           # Month Day 
           0?2
           ( [/.-] )                     # (7)
           29
           \7 
        |                              # or,

           # Day Month   
           29
           ( [/.-] )                     # (8)
           0?2
           \8 
      )

      # Leap Years  1900 - 2999
      (?:
           19
           (?:
                0 [48] 
             |  1 [26] 
             |  2 [048] 
             |  3 [26] 
             |  4 [048] 
             |  5 [26] 
             |  6 [048] 
             |  7 [26] 
             |  8 [048] 
             |  9 [26] 
           )
        |  2
           (?:
                [048] 
                (?:
                     0 [048] 
                  |  1 [26] 
                  |  2 [048] 
                  |  3 [26] 
                  |  4 [048] 
                  |  5 [26] 
                  |  6 [048] 
                  |  7 [26] 
                  |  8 [048] 
                  |  9 [26] 
                )
             |  [1235679] 
                (?:
                     0 [48] 
                  |  1 [26] 
                  |  2 [048] 
                  |  3 [26] 
                  |  4 [048] 
                  |  5 [26] 
                  |  6 [048] 
                  |  7 [26] 
                  |  8 [048] 
                  |  9 [26] 
                )
           )
      )
 )
 $
```

Comment: I just changed to my regular expression to yours one, [like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xligly8abRKEuEAuJApC?p=preview) , but seems still this can't identify correct formats

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane - I just changed _**your regular expression to  `const DOB_REGEX = /.*?/;`**_ and get this result: `3/1/7` passes `3/1` fails. What does _my_ regex have to do with your code?